# codigo em C, url=inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)ip->h_addr); não entendo o que está havendo

Tags: c, c++, socket, sintaxe

Eu estava estudando sockets por esse material https://www.exploit-db.com/papers/13634/
e me deparei com um código que me não entendo o que está havendo. A parte do código é essa:

```
struct hostent *ip;
...
// função da lib netdb.h para converter ai nosso host para IP
  ip = gethostbyname(host);
  url=inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)ip->h_addr);
  strcat(getpage,page);
  printf("%s",getpage);
```

A linha que começa com 'url' é que eu não entendo o que está havendo.
Do que eu ja pesquisei até agora descobri que:
  a struct hostent possui os campos

```
char  *h_name;            /* official name of host */
char **h_aliases;         /* alias list */
int    h_addrtype;        /* host address type */
int    h_length;          /* length of address */
char **h_addr_list; /* list of addresses */
```

e o campo `h_addr` que equivale 
   `char **h_addr_list[0];  //primeira posiçao do vetor h_addr_list`.
    `gethostbyname()` retorna um `hostent`(struct!) para a variavel 'ip', então acessando ip->h_addr estou acessando um ponteiro que é do tipo `char`, mas está sendo feito cast para ponteiro de `struct in_addr`:

`url=inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)ip->h_addr);`
mas `h_addr` não é uma struct in_addr(que possui um unsigned long) e para completar, esse asterisco * que vem antes de `(struct in_addr *)` o que está fazendo? não entendi essa sintaxe...
pesquisei bastante mas ainda não entendi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E ae cara! tudo bem?

> mas h_addr não é uma struct in_addr(que possui um unsigned long)

Exatamente, como `gethostbyname()` pode retornar um `hostent.h_addr_list` contendo addrs do tipo `in_addr` ou `in6_addr` e por esse motivo que `hostent.h_addr_list` é um `**char`. dessa forma sendo necessário o cast.

obs. para verificar qual tipo de addr, você pode fazer uma cast para `sockaddr` e verificar o campo `sa_family` e fazer o cast correspondente.

```
sockaddr *addr = (struct sockaddr *)ip->h_addr;

if(addr.sa_family == INET_ADDR)
{
  in_addr* ipv4 = (struct in_addr*)addr;
}
else if(addr.sa_family == INET6_ADDR)
{
  in6_addr* ipv6 = (struct in_addr*)addr;
}
else
{
  // erro
}
```

> para completar, esse asterisco * que vem antes de (struct in_addr *) o que está fazendo?

de acordo com a declaração `char *inet_ntoa(struct in_addr in);` o parametro **in** não é um ponteiro e é por isso que é utilizado o * no ponteiro, para pegar a instancia do object e o object ser copiado e não referenciado.

espero ter sido claro.

Comment: Muito claro, parabéns e muito obrigado cara.

Comment: Observando que tens um bom conhecimento sobre o assunto gostaria somente de perguntar se sabe sobre algum material que cubra bem sockets e typecasting, porque apesar de entender ainda não dominei completamente como eu quero essa parte(typecasting) e estou aprendendo sockets mas alguns materiais que peguei não são muito bons. O único que eu considero que vale a pena desses é o **Hacking: the art of exploitation**. Que possui um conteúdo sobre C Muito bom, e fica também  como dica em agradecimento.

Comment: que cubra socket **e** typecast não, mas para socket eu tenho um ótimo material que é esse [link](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/Sockets.html).
se você quiser entender melhor sobre typecast, procure entender sobre memory padding and align. isso vai te dar um bom entendimento sobre o assunto.
seu primeiro passo pode ser começando aqui [link](https://0xc0de.wordpress.com/2008/10/31/alinhamento-alignment-e-preenchimento-padding/).

Comment: se minha resposta foi a correta, por favor marque o post como resolvido para ajudar outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida (e ajudar com pontinhos! kkk...).

Comment: usuario sem experiencia no stackoverflow aqui, ai esqueci de marcar kkk mas está ai marcado, e obrigado de novo.